# Python complex select query TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql

I am beginner to use python with postgres. i have used following select query which returns unsupported character error initially. then I have used `%%Barge%% for instead %`. Eventhough I got error.

> ```
> not all arguments converted during string formatting.
> ```

Could someone help on this?

**Error 1:**

```
cur.execute("select a.client_sid,client.client_name,login.username,a.login_sid,a.action_date,a.origination_ip,a.action from activity_log a INNER JOIN login ON a.login_sid=login.login_sid  INNER JOIN client ON client.client_sid = a.client_sid where a.client_sid=(%s) AND action LIKE %Barge% AND action_date > current_date - interval '30 day';",acc )
ValueError: unsupported format character 'B' (0x42) at index 270
```

**Error 2**:

```
cur.execute("select a.client_sid,client.client_name,login.username,a.login_sid,a.action_date,a.origination_ip,a.action from activity_log a INNER JOIN login ON a.login_sid=login.login_sid  INNER JOIN client ON client.client_sid = a.client_sid where a.client_sid=(%s) AND action LIKE %%Barge%% AND action_date > current_date - interval '30 day';",acc )
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

**Code**:

```
  cur.execute("select a.client_sid,client.client_name,login.username,a.login_sid,a.action_date,a.origination_ip,a.action from activity_log a INNER JOIN login ON a.login_sid=login.login_sid  INNER JOIN client ON client.client_sid = a.client_sid where a.client_sid=(%s) AND action LIKE '%Barge%' AND action_date > current_date - interval '30 day';",acc )
```

Comment: You could pass `'%Barge%'` as a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `'%Barge%'` as a query parameter.

Something like this:

```
cur.execute("select a.client_sid,client.client_name,login.username,a.login_sid,a.action_date,a.origination_ip,a.action "
            " from activity_log a INNER JOIN login ON a.login_sid=login.login_sid  "
            " INNER JOIN client ON client.client_sid = a.client_sid "
            " where a.client_sid=(%s) AND action LIKE %s "
            " AND action_date > current_date - interval '30 day';",
           [acc, '%Barge%'])
```

Comment: I got below error.    [acc, '%Barge%']))
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Then you typed some invalid syntax somewhere. Why do you have two `))` at the end?

Comment: thanks @khelwood.. below query works fine.. slight modification.. cur.execute("""select a.client_sid,client.client_name,login.username,a.login_sid,a.action_date,a.origination_ip,a.action  from activity_log a INNER JOIN login ON a.login_sid=login.login_sid INNER JOIN client ON client.client_sid = a.client_sid  where a.client_sid=(%s) AND action LIKE %s AND action_date > current_date - interval '30 day';""",(acc, '%Barge%',))

Comment: date is not converted! and rest of the things are fine.. i got output like 'datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 27, 4, 52, 28, 244000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)'

Comment: If you have a new problem, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying a string in your sql query string you need to enclose it in single quotes `'`. To escape the percent you need a double percent `%%`. Putting these together we have `'%%Barge%%'`

The second parameter to execute (the values) must be in a tuple. If the argument is a single value it must be in a tuple of length one: `(acc,)`.

Joining two tables using the same field name can be doing using the more concise `USING (field_name)` instead of `ON a.field_name=b.field_name`.

Putting all of these together we have:

```
cur.execute("""
    SELECT client_sid, client.client_name, login.username, login_sid, a.action_date, a.origination_ip, a.action
    FROM activity_log a
    INNER JOIN login USING (login_sid)
    INNER JOIN client USING (client_sid)
    WHERE client_sid=%s AND action LIKE '%%Barge%%' AND action_date > current_date - interval '30 day';
    """,
    (acc,))
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using f strings. Here is an example:

```
  cur.execute(f"select a.client_sid,client.client_name,login.username,a.login_sid,a.action_date,a.origination_ip,a.action from activity_log a INNER JOIN login ON a.login_sid=login.login_sid  INNER JOIN client ON client.client_sid = a.client_sid where a.client_sid='{acc}' AND action LIKE '%Barge%' AND action_date > current_date - interval '30 day';")
```

Comment: Gluing variables into sql is generally a bad idea as it leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Hi brother, i used f string as well.. no luck.  ```cur.execute(f"select a.client_sid,client.client_name,login.username,a.login_sid,a.action_date,a.origination_ip,a.action from activity_log a INNER JOIN login ON a.login_sid=login.login_sid  INNER JOIN client ON client.client_sid = a.client_sid where a.client_sid=(%s) AND action LIKE %Barge% AND action_date > current_date - interval '30 day';",acc )
ValueError: unsupported format character 'B' (0x42) at index 270```

Comment: What values does the acc variable hold? If it is a string, the example above should work.

Comment: function argument.. 'acc' would hold some numbers .. like 358..364.. etc... while iterating through loop each time

Comment: dude, have you tried using the example I provided? From what it seems you only added an f in front of the string without changing anything else.

Comment: sorry Edgg.. your query also works.. but it doesn't interpolate date and time.. for 'action_date' it should return '2021-07-27 04:52:28.244+00'. but i got  output like 'datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 27, 4, 52, 28, 244000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)'

Comment: This is a dangerous answer see [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries): "Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint. "